# How to calculate correlation matrix from pandas containing tabulated data

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, correlation

Here is my input file:

```
inputfile_pd=pd.DataFrame([['2018-02-02',10, 2], ['2018-02-02',1, 3], ['2018-02-02',3, 4], ['2018-02-03',3, 2], ['2018-02-03',2, 3], ['2018-02-03',4, 4],  ['2018-02-04',4, 3],['2018-02-04',1, 4]], columns=['DateOfSale','Sales','Client_id'])
```

therefore it looks like:

```
   DateOfSale  Sales  Client_id
0  2018-02-02     10          2
1  2018-02-02      1          3
2  2018-02-02      3          4
3  2018-02-03      3          2
4  2018-02-03      2          3
5  2018-02-03      4          4
6  2018-02-04      4          3
7  2018-02-04      1          4
```

What is the simplest way to  calculate correlation matrix for sales to clients with various id's in this table?

the answer I am looking for may look like this

```
           Client2_sales Client3_sales Client4_sales
Client2_sales   some val     some val      some val  
Client3_sales   some val     some val      some val  
Client4_sales   some val     some val      some val
```

Comment: The vectors you want to correlate, are they one for each client, with each row being a separate DateOfSale?

Comment: Yes. every vector for a distinct client_id containing sales to this client at a given date.

Comment: did you check the answer in anyway?

Comment: @MickL, guess I answered the question. Please accept and upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

```
inputfile_pd.pivot('DateOfSale','Client_id').corr()

                Sales                    
Client_id           2         3         4
      Client_id                          
Sales 2           1.0 -1.000000 -1.000000
      3          -1.0  1.000000 -0.785714
      4          -1.0 -0.785714  1.000000
```

Comment: @Mickl, you might accept or respond to anwers. people put in effort to help you.